# Select distinct on pivot table by date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

Let's say there's data like this

```
date          trans
15-8-2020     trx-001
16-8-2020     trx-001
15-8-2020     trx-002
```

what i want to insert it into pivot table and select distinct on trans but, when there's duplicate, use the earlier one

this is what i'd expected:

```
date          trans
15-8-2020     trx-001
15-8-2020     trx-002
```

Comment: So you need it to be a pivot table, or is a formula solution sufficient. In that case, do you have Office 365? (UNIQUE/XLOOKUP)

Comment: Or add your table to the Data Model and use a measure within Power Pivot.